# Why binded command in listbox template can't run?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Why buttons in listbox can't run binded command?
I bind this command for simple button(not template) and it's working perfectly. 
Main.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="lbTemp">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Height="50" Text="{Binding}"/>
            <Button Height="20" Content="click" Command="{Binding Path=TestCommand}" CommandParameter="hello"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" Width="500" Height="300" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource lbTemp}" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.MyData}"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding Path=TestCommand}" CommandParameter="hello" Width="200" Height="40"/>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel.cs

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel() { }

    public ObservableCollection<string> MyData {
        get
        {
            return _MyData;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!_MyData.SequenceEqual(value))
            {
                _MyData = value;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<string> _MyData = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string caller="")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
    }

    private ICommand _testCommand;
    public ICommand TestCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _testCommand;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_testCommand != value)
            {
                _testCommand = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And Command.cs

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    public RelayCommand(Action action, Func<object, bool> canExecutePredicate)
    {
        if (action == null || canExecutePredicate == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Can't be null");
        this._action = action;
        this._canExecutePredicate = canExecutePredicate;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action action) : this(action, (obj) => true) { }

    Action _action;
    Func<object, bool> _canExecutePredicate;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    protected virtual void OnCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecutePredicate(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Can you say valid xaml example for this solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataContext` of the two `Button`s are different. Let's take a look at the `DataContext` for some of the elements in your view.

- The `Window`'s `DataContext` is your `ViewModel` class.
- The `ListBox`'s `DataContext` is the same as the `Window`'s. There should be no need for the use of `RelativeSource` in the `ItemsSource` binding you have set up.
- The `Button` outside the `DataTemplate` also has the same `DataContext` as the `Window`. That's why this `Command` binding works fine.
- The `Button` inside the `DataTemplate` has a `DataContext` of the particular item it is representing from the `MyData` collection you have created inside your `ViewModel` class. Importantly, it is *not* the `ViewModel` class itself.

Here is where I *would* use `RelativeSource`.

```
<Button Height="20" Content="click" Command="{Binding DataContext.TestCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}}" CommandParameter="hello"/>
```

Please let me know if this does not work for you.

Comment: Thanks Man! Working perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because the TestCommand is a property on ViewModel - not on the elements (strings) of the MyData collection.

You'll have to make a class:

```
class MyItemClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public string Text {get;set;}
   private ICommand _testCommand;
    public ICommand TestCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _testCommand;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_testCommand != value)
            {
                _testCommand = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string caller="")
   {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
    }
  }
```

You should then fill your MyData collection with items of that type where the TextBlocks binding should be changed to Text in the DataTemplate.

BTW: you don't have to have a relativesource reference in the itemssource binding of the list box. It inherits the DataContext from the Window, so it should be sufficient just to use {Binding MyData}.

Comment: This is simple test app, for testing wpf data template. For filling MyData I use this code:
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables().Values.Cast<string>().ToList();
MyData = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>(GetCollection());
And:
TestCommand = new RelayCommand(() => MessageBox.Show("test command"), (obj)=> true);

Comment: OK, but then you violate the idea of view models, because your button on each element activates a command on another object, which is possible but quite odd in my opinion :-)